# How to go to texture edit mode?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm new to blender and I was UV editing of it and after this I wanna go to the 3d viewport and go to texture editor mode can anyone tell me how?'m using version 2.90..
I wanna do this so that the colour on the UV unwrap can also applied on my object.[image]

Comment: You have to create a material for the object with the texture and go to material view mode.

Comment: Thanks for ur help!But are u sure it'll help...I will try this also...Thank you bro!